# GraphQL [Apollo-Android]: two `.watcher().enqueueAndWatch` creating infinite refresh loop

Tags: kotlin, graphql, apollo, apollo-android

I'm requesting a list of 'posts' from my server using `enqueueAndWatch` and it is causing an infinite refresh loop.

The two queries are below:

```
query GetOrganizationPosts {
    user {
        organization {
            posts {
                ...post
            }
        }
    }
}

query GetUserPosts {
    user {
        posts {
            ...post
        }
    }
}

fragment post on Post {
    id
    title
    messsage
}
```

The view model is initialized and the infinite loop occurs when I call `refreshPosts()` from the posts fragment:

```
init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
            networkClient.apolloClient.
                query(GetOrganizationPostsQuery())
                .watcher().enqueueAndWatch(callback)
            networkClient.apolloClient
                .query(GetUserPostsQuery())
                .watcher().enqueueAndWatch(callback2)
    }
}
fun refreshPosts() {
        networkClient.apolloClient
            .query(GetOrganizationPostsQuery())
            .enqueue(null)
        networkClient.apolloClient
            .query(GetUserPostsQuery())
            .enqueue(null)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround as described in Apollo-Android pull request: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/issues/2226

Add `.responseFetcher(ApolloResponseFetchers.CACHE_ONLY)` to any `enqueueAndWatch` calls. This makes sure watchers don't perform network requests when the cache is updated.